# Which Salesforce course would be best fit as per my background?

Tags: workflow, deployment

As we know these days salesforce is a valuable certification for your knowledge as well as resume, i am planning to do so!
By background, my profile is related to Business process management (tools like PEGA, IBM BPM) and business analyst or business system analyst, i would like to get expert opinion that which salesforce course and certification would be best fit for my profile and why that can help me perform better and open more opportunities for me? As per the few internet articles i have been through, i think salesforce ADMIN would be best fit but i am not sure!
Please guide to your best.
thank you.

Comment: I guess a good question to ask yourself is what do you do in/with salesforce and which course best represents what you do?

Answer (score 1):

For BA's I would recommend the Salesforce Sales Cloud or Service Cloud Consultant certification. There is a lot of guideline material available for preparing you for the exam. Additionally you should familiarise yourself with the TrailHead system provided by Salesforce.

Comment: You do need to do the Certified Administrator before doing the Consultancy Certifications.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce Certifications are industry recognised qualifications that prove to employers or clients that you excel in a certain field within Salesforce. There are multiple routes of Salesforce Qualifications, Administrator, Developer, Implementation Experts, App Builders, Architects, Pardot and Marketers. Each of these have different levels of qualifications.

The Salesforce Certified Administrator is where you can start, this will provide you the basics of Salesforce, its standard and custom objects, automation and most importantly, it’s security model. From there, you can likely specialise depending on your personal career goals.

If you go to http://certification.salesforce.com/ there is lots of good information about the certification program. I would suggest you start with the basic admin and then you can move to the Consultant exams (Sales Cloud/Service Cloud/Marketing Cloud etc). Salesforce Administrator is a good place to start as it will give you an overview of the platform and features. The important thing to know about Salesforce is you can build application without writing a singe line of code. Just Point and Click. That's the beauty of Salesforce platform.

You can start with [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/) to know moe on Salesforce platform and its features.

Good luck!